# Using Windows Multipoint Server 2011, Is there a log for number of times a program has been run?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, logging, windows-multipoint-server

Is there something built-in to Windows MultiPoint Server 2011 to log which users have logged in, how long they've been logged in and which programs they've run?

I'd even settle for a simple run count for all applications - not even user specific.

I'm looking for something that is built-in to Windows - does this exist?  I've looked at the logs, but it's a little too low-level.

I'm not using AD, and my set up is nComputing X550s (10 thin clients) and not networked in any other way.

If this doesn't exist, is there open-source/free software that I can install on WMS 2011 (not everything works with WMS)?